# Toggle text to display on a location with a mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to be able to click an area (box) and make some text appear, then click anywhere else on the page again to make it disappear. I started it with hovering it over the box, and it works fine. The text appears after the mouse hover overs it.

This is the jsfiddle of what i got: http://jsfiddle.net/TW2Le/73/

I tried to change `:hover` to `:active` , but it still does not work. what should I do to make it click-show, click-anywhere-else to hide.

Comment: So basically you're looking for a click event handler in CSS ?

Comment: You won't get it from CSS alone. It's very doable with JavaScript, though.

Comment: @adeneo Yes, could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, why not! posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the checkbox hack, using a hidden checkbox with a label to capture clicks in CSS only, and then using the adjacent sibling selector to change the elements visiblity.

This uses CSS only to capture the clicks, no javascript :

```
.wrap {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    height: 107px;
    width: 130px;
    display: block;
}

.noshow, #click, #click:checked ~ .show {display : none;}

.noshow {
    color: #050505;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height: 1em; 
    font-size:small;
}

#click:checked ~ .noshow {
    display: block;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TW2Le/88/)

For a jQuery version that reverts the click when clicking anywhere outside the box, you'd do

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if ( $(e.target).closest('.wrap').length ) {
            $('.show').hide();
            $('.noshow').show();
        }else{
            $('.show').show();
            $('.noshow').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TW2Le/89/)

Comment: Thanks for the nice example, right now I am trying to be able to click it anywhere else on the page to toggle back to "No Click", what do I have to add?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with CSS, this is hard enough to do as there are no click events in CSS. I'll add a javascript answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Remove you `:hover` css styles

Add Javascript handler for click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".noshow").hide();
    $(".wrap").click(function(){
        $(".show").toggle();
        $(".noshow").toggle();
    });
});
```

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EU53E/

Comment: thank you very much, how do I make the text to appear on the right side of the page?

Comment: simply...using css :)

Comment: and make sure `wrap` class has `width:100%` assigned!! :D

Answer (score 0):

add javascript and remove hover

```
 $(function(){
       $(".noshow").hide();
       $(".wrap").on('click',function(){
       $(".noshow,.show").toggle();
        });
    });
```